# Property for data annotations missing when generating client using NSwag

Tags: c#, nswag

I have a project (C# API and Blazor WebAssembly client side).
I have this data annotation on one of my property.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "My custom error message")]
    public string Client { get; set; }
```

I'm using NSwag to generate my client side. NSwag generates this:

```
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("client", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Client { get; set; }
```

So property "ErrorMessage" was not generated.
It should generate:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true, ErrorMessage = "My custom error message")]
```

I can add this manually, but I would like that NSwag generates this. Is this not possible or am I missing something?

*I've found this similar topic https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2297#issuecomment-524640331 but I can't help myself with it.